# Подскажите, что значит такая запись в PHP?

Tags: php

Подскажите, что значит такая запись в PHP?

```
isset( $r[ $i ] ) ? $r[ $i ] :
```

Comment: Там после двоеточия должно стоять значение, которое возвращается, если условие не выполняется

Comment: такая запись в пхп называется [тернарный оператор](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: @teran благодарю!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Условие, т.е если есть элемент массива, то равен ей, если нет то, к примеру, null